# odds / percent is the game flawed or this seem accurate

Tags: probability

Playing a game with 2 possible outcomes (win / loss), and having been told it's a 17% chance of success (win):

- my first time playing, I won on my 7th attempt;
- my second time playing, it took me 23 attempts before I won;
- my third time playing, it took me 13 attempts before I won.

What are the odds of me failing that many times? I believe the 17% is a lie. Or do those seem likely results for a 17% success rate?

Comment: Note: 17% is probably rounded off from $\frac{1}{6}$. That might give you some insight into why it's alleged to have that win rate. Is it based around dice, perhaps?

Comment: The number of wins is definitely on the low side. The samle size is however to small to reach definite conclusions.

Answer (score 2):

The chance of $3$ wins in $43$ tries is ${43 \choose 3}p^3(1-p)^{40}$ for a single game winning probability of $p$.  Assuming $p=0.17$, [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2843%20choose%203%290.17%5E3%2a0.83%5E40) gets this as about $3.5\%$, so it should happen more than once in thirty runs.  The chance of less than $3$ is rather small, so will not impact this.  Not too convincing that the $17\%$ is badly wrong.

Comment: If we believe the quoted win percentage is $\frac 16$ the chance for $3$ of $43$ becomes about $3.887\%$